# Start Emacs Markdown Mode in CONTENTS view

Tags: markdown-mode

I've been trying to have `Markdown Mode` open all markdown files in `CONTENTS` view, i.e. all folded up. I can of course just hit `S-TAB` twice whenever I open a markdown file, but, with [markdown-mode.el](https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode/blob/master/markdown-mode.el) available I shouldn't need to. I can only see one likely variable to tweak - `markdown-cycle-global-status`. I attempted to tweak this this in my `init.el`:

```lisp
(use-package markdown-mode
    :mode ("\\.markdown\\'" "\\.md\\'")
    :init
    ; (setq markdown-cycle-global-status 3) ; doesn't trigger CONTENTS
    (setq markdown-command "pandoc"))
; (add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook
    ; (lambda ()
    ; (setq markdown-cycle-global-status 3))) ; doesn't trigger CONTENTS
```

The trailing comments "doesn't..." follow code that, when uncommented, has no effect, though I thought it might. So I tried tweaking `~/.emacs.d/straight/repos/markdown-mode/markdown-mode.el`:

```lisp
(defvar markdown-cycle-global-status 3) ; by default it's 1
```

- still not opening md's in CONTENTS view.

So any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a defvar and not a defcustom my guess is that the mode isn't designed for you to customize that variable, so I would instead copy some of the code from the `markdown-cycle` command :-(

```
(use-package markdown-mode
    :mode ("\\.markdown\\'" "\\.md\\'")
    :preface
    (defun my/markdown-set-global-status ()
      (outline-hide-sublevels 1)
      (setq markdown-cycle-global-status 3)
      (markdown-outline-fix-visibility)
      )
    :init
    (add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook #'my/markdown-set-global-status)
    (setq markdown-command "pandoc"))
```

Comment: That partially works in my configuration: only the first `(markdown-cycle t)` is respected, getting me to `OVERVIEW` (then the first `S-TAB` has no effect).

Comment: Oh wow, that markdown-cycle code didn't work like I thought. I think at this point the simplest thing is to copy the code from markdown-cycle :-( so I will update my answer.

Comment: Just for reference, from your first version I used just one line, `:preface (defun my/markdown-OVERVIEW () (markdown-cycle t))`, which got me to `OVERVIEW`. Your edited code does get me directly into `CONTENTS` view, but with one disadvantage: 1st `S-TAB` (bound to `markdown-shifttab`) reports "OVERVIEW" though nothing has changed in the buffer; 2nd `S-TAB` reports "CONTENTS", again no change in the buffer; 3rd `S-TAB` successfully gets `SHOW ALL`, and from then cycles through those three views as expected. Any ideas how to get `S-TAB` immediately fully functional?